# how do i create a steam game shortcut anywhere that's not the deskto-?

Tags: shortcuts

i'm new to ubuntu so there might be a really obvious answer to this but I'm trying to create a games folder on my desktop except the .desktop files don't work there, what do i do?

for kanehekili:
contents of the shortcut are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Project Arrhythmia
Comment=Play this game on Steam
Exec=steam steam://rungameid/440310
Icon=steam_icon_440310
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your desktop file (paste it into your question, **not** into the comments)

Comment: @kanehekili edited the post

Comment: Looks correct. What happens, if you execute this line in a terminal:
`steam steam://rungameid/440310`. Does it start, or do get an error?  You might try with `/usr/bin/stream stream:...`

Comment: @kanehekili it launches the game, so how do I make a shortcut to that with an icon?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work that way on the Ubuntu desktop. Instead, you can create a Games folder in the Application overview, and place your games there.

Note that your Ubuntu desktop is invisible most of the time while you work. The application overview, however, is one mouse click away on the dock, or can be summoned quickly with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Note, in addition, that, this way, your games are searchable. Hit <kbd>Super</kbd>, type a few letters of the name of the game and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It cannot get more efficient than that.

Comment: Finally I understood the question. It never occurred to me that he wanted to have an icon on the desktop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents of the desktop file is correct, moving the desktop file into

`/home/<user>/.local/share/applications`

should do the trick.

Ensure that the desktop file has the right settings:

> -rw-r--r-- 1   2396  7. Aug 01:38 mysteam.desktop

where <user> is your user name. You can check this entry by issuing from your home directory:

`ls -la .local/share/applications/mysteam.desktop` (or whatever the name of your desktop file is).

Then your desktop entry can be searched via activities. If found, you may drop it into your "Favorites" bar